# Perl script: different results form command line and CGI

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

Warning: I'm perl and CGI beginner so this can be stupid question.

I write a really simple perl script which should get info about open files and running processes on system. There is something like this function for processes:

```
sub num_processes() {
    my @lines = `/bin/ps -ef`;
    return scalar @lines;
}
```

If I run it from bash, it returns all running processes on system but when I run it via apache and CGI it retruns only 2 processes (running script and running 'ps -ef'). This CGI script runs under user with shell (/bin/bash) enabled. Is there any posibility how to get all the processes via apache and CGI?

Comment: so `num_processes` returns size of `@lines` array?

Answer (score 1):

Your CGI script will run as the Apache user account. Your shell call will run as your user account. This is probably why you get two different answers. Take a look at something like [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html) to manage the user under which CGI scripts are run.

Comment: Thanks for reaction but I forgot to add info, that the user who runs scipt is different from apache one (thanks to suexec) and has a shell enabled.

Comment: Two different users will see different process lists, so you are probably running into expected behavior.